# How can i find out what version of IIS i need to deploy ASP.NET+VB App?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis

I just got application written in ASP.NET and VB, can i deploy it on any IIS?

Are there any files in project with that kind of information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no files or magic numbers anywhere that can tell you this. Chances are preety good that it will run on a newer versions of IIS but even then your goign to need to know what functionality it requires. For example is it using WebDav? IIS is preety good at being backwards compatible but forward compability not so good. For example IIS7 introduced new functionality which if the application is using it, would prevent it from running on IIS6.

Do you know what version of .net it requires that is more likely to bite you then anything else?

Answer (score 1):

Any IIS that supports ISAPI, I guess, but IIS 5.1 + is recommended (.NET probably won't run on OS that run IIS4 anyway).

Answer (score 1):

IIS 6 is the minimum for recent .NET versions (i.e. Windows 2003) because Win2000 is not supported (considering server only here).

The Windows version will tell you the IIS version:

Server 2003: IIS 6
Server 2008: IIS 7
Server 2008 R2: IIS 7.5

Also XP: IIS5.1; Vista: IIS7

Comment: If you are running XP as a dev machine.  It'll run 3.5 fine.

Comment: Added... to avoid others missing the "considering server only here".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good MSDN link detailing which IIS version comes with which version of Windows as well as useful links for configuring it.

[ASP.NET and IIS Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178477.aspx)